# Calculate the value according to the dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good afternoon, I have a doubt on how to make a calculation, as for examples I have a face 'date' and a face 'date end' when selected these dates it will calculate a value, for example for * 38.00 reais and calculates by "end date." If you can give me strength, thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense. Are you saying you want to calculate how many days there are between a start date and an end date? Then times the number of days by 38? Maybe momentjs can help you?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the number of dayas between two dates ? The end date given a starting date plus a number of days ? do you want the result in days ? do your want the result in hours ? Do you want to use datetimes or just dates ?

Comment: Good afternoon, sorry for not expressing myself well, I'll put my code as I'm doing, my problem I'm having is picking the start and end date, inside it will multiply by $ * 38 value that corresponds to each day ie put a date 10/12/2017 and end date 12/14/2017, you will have 4 days that will multiply by 38 * value and give the result in total value of 38 * 4 days = 152.00 $

Comment: 3 days 10/12/2017 to 12/14/2017

Comment: sorry 10/12/17 , 13/12/17

Comment: you have lots of goog answer i think your only mistake was  daysPass = final.diff(date1, 'days'); where final is not a moment

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

      <script src="js/moment.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    function calc{
    var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("databegin").value);
    var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("dataend").value);

    date1 = Moment('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    date2 = Moment('DD/MM/YYYY'),

    daysPass = final.diff(date1, 'days');

    alert('Days: ' + daysPass); // Dias passados: 13
    alert('Value: R$' + (daysPass * 38) + ',00');

    }  


    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <fieldset id="c">
    <h3>Test:</h3>
      <input type="date" id="databegin"></br>
      <input type="date" id="dataend"></br>
      <button id="calc" onclick="calc();">Calc</button>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <fieldset>
    Result: <span id="result">0</span>
  </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```